# Difference between usage of Nor and And

Tags: neither-nor

> 1. He has never experienced joy, sadness **and** anger with such a great passion.
> 2. He has never experienced joy, sadness, **nor** anger with such passion before.”

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: If you change the second sentence, a comparison could be made. *2. He has experienced **neither** joy, sadness, nor anger with such passion before*. Alternatively, you could keep the second sentence as is, except for replacing **nor** with **or**.

Comment: I've never seen "neither A, B, nor C"; this site seems to support that in a series of more than two items, the "nor" must be repeated before each term after the first: https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-use-nor

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Using *nor* with more than two items is nonstandard, but it's still done. The method by which it's done varies between people and style guides. I was less concerned with picking a style than with replacing *never* with *neither*. In an answer, the various styles could be given.